# Mule Server 3.6 > Anypoint Studio > Raw JSON as POST data

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

Still learning Mulesoft's Anypoint Studio... I am confused as how will I be able to access raw JSON POST data via the HTTP Listener then use the Choice flow control to execute conditions based on a value from a given JSON index. Anyone can show/tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON HTTP body will automatically become the payload of your message in Mule probably represented as Stream.

Just for demo purposes, try logging the payload after your http:listener using:

```
<object-to-string-transformer />

<logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />
```

There best way to query JSON is to transform it to a Map suing the JSON module transformers.

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
```

And then query it using MEL like standard MVEL or Java syntax.

For a JSON document like: `{"person" : {"name" : "bob"}}`

```
<logger message="#[payload.person.name]" level="INFO" />
```

You can use these expressions in your choic router also:

```
<choice>
   <when expression="#[payload.person.name == 'bob']">
      do something ...
   </when>
</choice>
```

Comment: Thanks a loy @Ryan Carter